# importing Fragment and FragmentTransaction error

Tags: android-studio

when I am trying to import these two lines in my code
"import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;"
showing error like cannot resolve symbol fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you declare the dependencies in the Gradle?

It´s the first thing you need to do before an import.

Try this:

dependencies {

```
// Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:$fragment_version"
// Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
}
```

And check out this link! [Fragments Info](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)

Comment: @Sandhya mark my answer as correct, so other people with the same problem can check it out :D